# Testing file i/o with Perl - frameworks

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following command in pl script:

```
mkpath($my_dir,0,0777);
```

I want to test instances when it encounters errors when executing this command. Currently, I change permissions of the parent directory, or some other such change to the file system, to force an error. How would I set up a unit test, if possible, without altering the physical machine? I am reading up on Test::MockModule and Sub::Override, but not seeing how this could be used above. I have used Test::More in the past, but not for mocking or injection.

There are many other file system calls where errors may arise than the one shown above.

Expanding on below answer, I came up with the following shown below. Are there any caveats to below? I want to run the script, with 'bad' input to make sure I am capturing error conditions correctly.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More;
use Sub::Override;
use File::Path qw{ mkpath };

my $my_dir = "somedir";
my $err_msg = "";
sub testme { 
    eval {mkpath($my_dir, 0, 0777)};
    if ($@) {
        $err_msg = "Could not create directory $my_dir. Error was as follows: $@\n";
    }
    return $err_msg;
}

#The following will be a series of tests for different error conditions when script is run in test mode
{
    my $override = 'Sub::Override'->new('mkpath' => sub {
        my ($dir, $verbose, $mode) = @_;
        if ($dir eq "somedir") { $dir = "/baddir" };
        return File::Path::mkpath ($dir,$verbose, $mode);
    });

    my $res = testme(); #will check result with maybe "is" or "ok"
    print "Result of testme sub:$res\n";
}
```

Comment: `mkpath` is probably tested enough, so it's OK to mock it. See [Test::Spec::Mocks](http://p3rl.org/Test::Spec::Mocks) for another possiblity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{
    package TestMe;
    use File::Path qw{ mkpath };
    sub testme {
        mkpath('dir', 0, 0777);
    }
}

use Test::More;
use Sub::Override;

{
    my $override = 'Sub::Override'->new('TestMe::mkpath' => sub {
        my ($dir, $verbose, $mode) = @_;
        is $dir, 'dir', 'right dir';
        is $verbose, 0, 'no verbosity';
        is $mode, 0777, 'correct mode';
    });
    TestMe::testme();
}  # End of scope, $overrides si destroyed, original mkpath is restored.
```

Note that you override mkpath in the TestMe package, as it's been imported by the `use` clause.

Comment: Please see revision above.

Comment: `if ($@)` is dangerous, see [Bug in eval in pre-5.14](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1153468)

Comment: Thank you. This bug is all over, even in some remote CPAN.

Comment: `remove_tree( 'foo/bar', 'bar/rat', {error => \my $err} );
  if (@$err) {...}` This has no known bugs, correct?